# How to save the ListView contents to a text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to save the ListView contents (including the ColumnHeaders) to a text file?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in .NET that will do this for you, you need to do the work yourself.

On whatever event will trigger your save: open the file, iterate through the list content writing the text to the file and then close the file. The close can of course be done via `using`:

```
using (var tw = new StreamWriter(filename)) {
  foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items) {
    tw.WriteLine(item.Text); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export all the subitems you must use this code:

```
 StringBuilder sb;

 if (listView.Items.Count > 0)
 {
     // the actual data
     foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
     {
         sb = new StringBuilder();

         foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem listViewSubItem in lvi.SubItems)
         {
             sb.Append(string.Format("{0}\t", listViewSubItem.Text));
         }
         sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
     }
     sw.WriteLine();
 }
```

Comment: How could I read the file this creates to populate the ListView next time I start the application?

Answer (score 1):

This should work 100%, I made this for a project of mine. 
I know this is 4 years too late but here it is.

```
        private void export2File(ListView lv, string splitter)
        {
            string filename = "";
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

            sfd.Title = "SaveFileDialog Export2File";
            sfd.Filter = "Text File (.txt) | *.txt";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = sfd.FileName.ToString();
                if (filename != "")
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
                    {
                        foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", item.SubItems[0].Text, splitter, item.SubItems[1].Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a tab-character in between of each subitem and a break at the end. If someone uses copy&paste from the txt file to excel, it will bring up a sorted table into excel. Also, in the most texteditors it would show up formated.

Comment: Unnecessary... Extremely. All this is doing is formatting it specifically for 2 variables for the 2 sub items. No clue why someone would be using excel. Most text editors would format this just fine except for notepad.

Comment: No clue? Because it is data in a table. No way to tell if it is necessary or not as long as you dont know which kind of data is handled in the tool.

Comment: You don't need to call Close() at the end, the "using" statement is disposing the object for you.